# Installing perl modules

Tags: ubuntu, apt, perl, libraries

I was trying to install a perl module Future::Utils on my Ubuntu machine but didn't find the exact command. I tried this command but it didn't work:

```
sudo apt-get install libfuture-utils-perl
```

I have this result when i run this command:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libfuture-perl
```

Can you help me resolve this issue

Comment: What happened when you ran that `apt-get` command? Please [edit] your question to include this information, including any error messages you may have got.

Answer (score 5):

On my Debian system running your command gave me this result

```
apt-get install libfuture-utils-perl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libfuture-utils-perl
```

However, I found the library was available as a package by searching:

```
apt-cache search libfuture
libfuture-perl - module for operations awaiting completion
```

I was then able to install it:

```
apt-get install libfuture-perl
```

Comment: If it's not a built package then `cpan install Future::Utils` will probably do the trick.

Comment: @Sobrique good point, but since the package exists there's little reason at the outset for not using it. (Good contra-reasons include CPAN having a significantly newer version.)

Comment: @roaima Thankyou for your answer i try to install libfuture-perl and I have the same error

Comment: What result do you get from the `apt-cache` command I suggested? Have you run `apt-get update` recently?

Answer (score 0):

Perl module names correspond to a `.pm` file path out of a necessity -- not any specific rule of the languague, but because that's how perl finds them.  This assumption can be used with `apt-file search` to determine which distro package, if any, contains that file:

```
apt-file search  "/Future/Utils.pm"
```

There are a lot of modules with no package, however, and the easiest way to get those is directly from CPAN, for which the `cpan` utility provides an interactive interface.  It is probably already installed if perl is.   The first time you use it, it will ask to do a bit of auto-configuration.  You probably want to `su root` first, so that you can install to the system rather than a user home, and so the cpan config is saved in the right place (root's home directory). Then you just `install Future::Utils` from the `cpan` prompt.  Installing a module this way may require build tools if there is XS code involved; cpan will let you know about this and tell you what you need to install first.  You may also sometimes require specific libraries and the development header packages for them.

You can have multiple versions of a module installed, one from a distro package and one from CPAN, since they go to different places by default.  The CPAN one is what will get used, however, since its path takes precedence in the `@INC` array -- but you can change this or set `$PERL5LIB` (a shell environment, not perl, variable).